# ForceClose Error in RadioGroup with onCheckedlistner

Tags: android, radio-group

I've got a question heres my Code:

```
    package de.retowaelchli.filterit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.ADFilterDBAdapter;


public class ADFilterConfigActivity extends Activity {

    //Variablen deklaration
    private ADFilterDBAdapter mDbHelper;
    private String name;
    private String keyword;
    private String cache;
    private String save;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.autodelete_config);
        radiobuttoncheck();

        //Hier wir die Datenbank aufgerufen
        mDbHelper = new ADFilterDBAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();


        //Hier werden die EditTextfelder gesucht
        EditText edtTextName=(EditText )findViewById(R.id.ADConfigName);
        EditText edtTextKeyword=(EditText )findViewById(R.id.ADConfigKeyword);

        //Hier wird der Inhalt der EditText boxen in einen String gespeichert
        name = edtTextName.getText().toString();
        keyword = edtTextKeyword.getText().toString();
        }

        private void radiobuttoncheck() {

        //Hier wird ausgewertet welcher Button geklickt wurde
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.adcachegroup);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, final int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.adcache_true:
                    save = new StringBuilder(save).append("true").toString();
                    cache = save.toString();

                    break;
                case R.id.adcache_false:
                    save = new StringBuilder(save).append("false").toString();
                    cache = save.toString();

                    break;
                        }
                }
            });
        }
 }
```

The Code doesnt show one Error in Eclipse but if i try to test the code on my Phone i get a ForceClose.

What I found is if i dont use the radiobuttoncheck it works. But i dunno whats the error in it.

Thx in Advance

safari

sorry forgot heres the logcat-log:

```
    08-31 10:35:22.823: INFO/ActivityManager(1740): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=de.retowaelchli.filterit/.StartseiteActivity } from pid 1867
08-31 10:35:22.843: VERBOSE/HtcAppUsageStats(1740): (launch app, package): (Filter It, de.retowaelchli.filterit)
08-31 10:35:22.863: INFO/ActivityManager(1740): Start proc de.retowaelchli.filterit for activity de.retowaelchli.filterit/.StartseiteActivity: pid=27542 uid=10150 gids={}
08-31 10:35:22.933: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1541): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 51% free 2684K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 78ms
08-31 10:35:23.033: INFO/SuperPowerSvc(2428): [SuperPowerSvc] App launched: [de.retowaelchli.filterit]
08-31 10:35:23.063: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1541): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 51% free 2684K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 88ms
08-31 10:35:23.143: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1541): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 51% free 2684K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 67ms
08-31 10:35:23.223: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1740): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 659K, 35% free 9759K/14855K, external 9725K/11773K, paused 151ms
08-31 10:35:23.473: WARN/ResourceType(1740): Skipping entry 0x7f040007 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
08-31 10:35:23.483: WARN/ResourceType(1740): Skipping entry 0x7f040008 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
08-31 10:35:23.603: DEBUG/dalvikvm(27542): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 50% free 2694K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 45ms
08-31 10:35:23.733: WARN/InputManagerService(1740): [unbindCurrentClientLocked] Disable input method client.
08-31 10:35:23.733: WARN/InputManagerService(1740): [startInputLocked] Enable input method client.
08-31 10:35:23.803: INFO/ActivityManager(1740): Displayed de.retowaelchli.filterit/.StartseiteActivity: +947ms (total +1m12s949ms)
08-31 10:35:24.963: INFO/ActivityManager(1740): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=de.retowaelchli.filterit/.ADeleteActivity } from pid 27542
08-31 10:35:24.973: INFO/SuperPowerSvc(2428): [SuperPowerSvc] App launched: [de.retowaelchli.filterit]
08-31 10:35:25.113: DEBUG/dalvikvm(27542): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 36K, 49% free 2767K/5379K, external 5760K/7192K, paused 21ms
08-31 10:35:25.313: INFO/ActivityManager(1740): Displayed de.retowaelchli.filterit/.ADeleteActivity: +350ms
08-31 10:35:26.743: INFO/ActivityManager(1740): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=de.retowaelchli.filterit/.ADFilterConfigActivity } from pid 27542
08-31 10:35:26.783: INFO/[POST_RESELECT](27542): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401090b8,-1,0,-1,0)
08-31 10:35:26.783: INFO/[POST_RESELECT](27542): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@40130050,-1,0,-1,0)
08-31 10:35:26.783: INFO/[POST_RESELECT](27542): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401090b8,-1,0,-1,0)
08-31 10:35:26.783: INFO/[POST_RESELECT](27542): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@40130050,-1,0,-1,0)
08-31 10:35:26.803: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(27542): Shutting down VM
08-31 10:35:26.803: WARN/dalvikvm(27542): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.retowaelchli.filterit/de.retowaelchli.filterit.ADFilterConfigActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at de.retowaelchli.filterit.ADFilterConfigActivity.radiobuttoncheck(ADFilterConfigActivity.java:46)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at de.retowaelchli.filterit.ADFilterConfigActivity.onCreate(ADFilterConfigActivity.java:26)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
08-31 10:35:26.803: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27542):     ... 11 more
08-31 10:35:26.813: WARN/ActivityManager(1740):   Force finishing activity de.retowaelchli.filterit/.ADFilterConfigActivity
08-31 10:35:26.813: WARN/ActivityManager(1740):   Force finishing activity de.retowaelchli.filterit/.ADeleteActivity
08-31 10:35:26.873: INFO/SuperPowerSvc(2428): [SuperPowerSvc] App launched: [de.retowaelchli.filterit]
08-31 10:35:27.323: WARN/ActivityManager(1740): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4094f4d8 de.retowaelchli.filterit/.ADFilterConfigActivity}
```

And Finally heres the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView 
        style="@style/NormalFont"
        android:text="@string/adconfig"     
        android:layout_weight="0.05" 
        android:clickable="false"
        />

        <TextView
            style="@style/SmallFont"
            android:text="@string/adname"
            android:layout_weight="0.03" />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/ADConfigName" 
            android:layout_weight="0.05" 
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            style="@style/SmallFont"
            android:text="@string/adkeyword"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/ADConfigKeyword" 
            android:layout_weight="0.05" 
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>

            <TextView
            style="@style/SmallFont"
            android:text="@string/adcache"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
             />
        <RadioGroup 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/adcachegroup" 
            android:id="@+id/adcache"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <RadioButton 
                android:text="Yes" 
                android:id="@+id/adcache_true" 
                android:layout_width="80dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton 
                android:text="No" 
                android:id="@+id/adcache_false" 
                android:layout_width="80dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup> 

        <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ADConfigMainsite"
            android:layout_weight="0.76"
            android:gravity="bottom">   
                <TableRow 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
                    android:id="@+id/ADConfigMainsite"
                    android:onClick="onClickADConfigSave"
                    android:layout_weight="0.05"
                    android:gravity="bottom">
                        <TextView   
                            android:text="@string/adconfigsave" 
                            style="@style/NormalFont"   
                            android:gravity="bottom"/>
                 </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the layout correct? You might get a null pointer while trying to bind a radiogroup to a non-existing resource. Please include the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a `StringBuilder` with a `null` string:

```
save = new StringBuilder(save).append("true").toString();
```

Initialize `save` string:

```
private String save = "";
```

**EDIT**: According to the locgat output widget with id `adcachegroup` cannot be found in the layout. Ensure you're setting a correct layout.